# Find duplicates based on two columns and then sum the other column

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a file that looks like this,

```
 REF     QUERY   COVR    COVQ
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_2     0.08    2.48
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_1     0.02    0.02
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_2      0.22    0.06
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_2      0.21    0.05
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_1     0.21    0.27
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_2     0.21    0.64
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_4      0.20    0.06
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_8      0.20    0.07
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_10     0.21    0.08
```

For each different combinations of column 1 and 2, or duplicates based on column 1 and 2, I want to sum column 4 (total coverage) and have the output file like this:

```
REF QUERY COVQ
sca_10_chr8_2_0  scaffold_2  1.52
sca_10_chr8_2_0  scaffold_1  0.29
sca_10_chr8_2_0  scaffold_4  0.06
sca_10_chr8_2_0  scaffold_8  0.07
sca_10_chr8_2_0  scaffold_10  0.08
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { print $1, $2, $4; next }
{ sum[$1 OFS $2] += $4 }
END {
    for (key in sum) {
        print key, sum[key]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
REF QUERY COVQ
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_8 0.07
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_10 0.08
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_1 0.29
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_2 3.23
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_4 0.06
```

I assume the expected output in your question is wrong since the above IS the sum of the 4th column values for every $1 and $2 pair.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. It worked and yes the expected output file values might be wrong in my question but what I wanted was sum of 4th column for every $1 and $2 pair.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
$ mlr --pprint --ofmt '%.2f' stats1 -a sum -g REF,QUERY -f COVQ yourfile
REF             QUERY       COVQ_sum
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_2  3.23
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_1  0.29
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_4  0.06
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_8  0.07
sca_10_chr8_2_0 scaffold_10 0.08
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately this program is not available in the supercomputer I am using. Do you have any idea how to do this using awk, sed, grep

Comment: @ambika it's impossible to do math with grep or sed so you can rule those out. grep is for doing `g/re/p` while sed is for doing `s/old/new/`.